# Is it possible to turn off Media audio mode in Bluetooth headset by programming?

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-bluetooth, headset

I have a headset device. I want to transfer my voice from the headset to my mobile. The mobile can play my sound via its speaker. Hence, I need to turn of Media audio in default setting (Left image) after headset connect with phone by Bluetooth. I am looking for a solution to turn off Media audio by programming such as right image. Could you suggest to me the solution for my work?

[image]

Comment: Hope this helps, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13014509/toggling-a2dp-device-android, Media audio is for A2DP profile

Answer (score 0):

If you are searching for ways to toggle audio while being connected to A2DP or Non-A2DP I have written a test application which can provide you the basic knowledge of audio routing. Github Repo for the test application:  https://github.com/sauravpradhan/Basic-Audio-Routing